# How to make JAVA method that accepts any object as parameter?

Tags: java, object, methods

Suppose i have a project with many objects of different kinds, but they all have an instance variable X, how do i make a method that accepts an object of any type, and returns X?

Dummy code example:

```
class Car{
int X =19;
}
class Apple{
int X =21;
}
class Bee{
int X =32;
}
public int GetX(Object ANY_OBJECT_HERE){
return ANY_OBJECT_HERE.X;
}
```

Comment: Define an interface with a `getX` method. Make all your classes implement that interface (possibly by returning the value of their field). Make your `GetX` method accept a parameter of the interface type and invoke its `getX` method.

Comment: Just as a coding standard, you shouldn't is a capital G for the method name. It should be `getX`

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options.

1. Create an interface, say, `Xholder`, with one method, `getX()` that returns `int`.  Have `Car`, `Apple`, and `Bee` implement `Xholder` by returning `X`.  Then, your current `GetX` method is unnecessary; anything that would have called `GetX(yourObject)` would now call `yourObject.getX()`.
2. Use reflection in `GetX`.  Get the object's class with `getClass()` and get the class's `Field` with `getField`, passing the variable name `"X"`.  From there you can get the value.

The first option is the best, because reflection is slower and more error-prone.

Comment: Yes, that is how i would normally do it by having a getter method inside the class of each type, but i need a generic method that can return a field from any object. Suppose i had a swing gui with many gui objects, and a method called GetWidth(Object ANYOBJECT), i would either have to define one method per type of object as in GetWidthOfButton(JButton button) etc... or come up with some generic method that works for any object...

Answer (score 2):

Two ways off the top of my head:

- Use an interface common to all objects that defines the getX() method
- Use reflection

That been said, your method interface is not correct: you do not expect ANY object, but only those who have that X property. That means that the first solution is, from a design perspective, the most correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make all your Classes extends from a base abstract class (Say MyObject which contains X) and make GetX parameter type be MyObject.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know that you could do this by using Polymorphism concepts with an interface or abstract method (of an abstract class);

You could resolve this issue by using Java Reflections. You can study more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the java.lang.Object as a Parameter?

Comment: Try to give an example when suggesting a solution to make it clearer. Thank you for contributing in Stack Overflow